# Refering to Files and Functions from within a Python package.

Tags: python, function, package

Let us have a look at the Directory structure of my Python Package

```
packman
 weights.py
  functions:
   weigh()
   force()
 relatives.py
  functions:
   roll()
   torque()
 __init__.py
 data
  work.txt
  rastor.txt
```

Now I have two questions.

Firstly suppose I want to access work.txt, from the function weigh() inside weights.py how would I address it? 
I initially tried with this

```
f = open("data/work.txt")
```

While this method does succesfully work when the code is run inside main. However it fails to find the file when it is used as a package and it raises the issue

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/work.txt'

How should I write the address of work.txt to make it more universal?

My other question is when I want to call the function weigh() of weights.py from the function roll() inside relatives.py, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a `main.py` or similar single entry point for my applications. Then I can do something like this to get the path for my application:

```
import os

app_location = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Now you can pass this location to your other modules or perhaps even use the same idea in them to get their location. Since you now have this location, you can easily do something like this:

```
data_location = os.path.join(app_location, 'data', 'work.txt')
with open(data_location) as f:
    # do something with the file object
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

As for your second question, just import `weights` into your `relatives.py` script and call `weights.weigh()`